# highslide - can you combine YouTube and Images on the same page?

Tags: javascript, highslide

I have looked into highslide.com script and I plan on using it on my site.

I have downloaded files, including youtube.html as show in example and the gallery-white.html. I plan on wanting to combine these two scripts into one page. I see they have used highslide-with-gallery.js and highslide-with-html.js. That means my page should be over 150KB for starters with those two javascript files.

What would be an ideal way to combine these files into a single file?

Answer (score 0):

Just use highslide-full.js, which is the complete script. The highslide-with-gallery.js and highslide-with-html.js scripts are each a subset of the full script, with a lot of overlap. You should *NEVER* load two versions of the Highslide script on one page. Doing so generates some fatal collisions.

If you're concerned about size, use highslide-full.min.js, which is a minified version of the complete script.

Comment: Demo with gallery white and YouTube video on the same page: http://roadrash.no/hs-support/gallery-white+youtube-video.html

Comment: Thanks very much for that guys. What's the difference between highslide-full.min.js and the full script and when should one be used over the other?

Comment: The only difference between highslide-full.js and highslide-full.min.js is the file size.

Comment: "Minified" just means compressed, like a zip file. The Javascript in highslide-full.js is identical to the Javascript in highslide-full.min.js. The minified version is just about unreadable in a text editor because of the compression, but the functionality is the same.